# Parsing a XML list in to a list in flutter

Tags: xml, flutter, dart, parsing

I am getting data from an API that contains an ID, a name, a category, and multiple images and other attributes.
My problem is with images, the XML is something like this:

```
<photoURLs>
   <photoURL> --URL-- </photoURL>
   <photoURL> --URL-- </photoURL>
   <photoURL> --URL-- </photoURL>
</photoURLs>
```

My object is defined like this:

```
class Pet {
  int id = 0;
  String name = '';
  String category = '';
  List<dynamic> photoUrls = [];
  List<dynamic> tags = [];
  String status = '';

  Pet(int id, String name, String category, List<dynamic> photoUrls,
      List<dynamic> tags, String status) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.category = category;
    this.photoUrls = photoUrls;
    this.tags = tags;
    this.status = status;
  }

  Pet.fromJson(Map json)
      : id = json['id'],
        name = json['name'],
        category = json['category']['name'],
        photoUrls = json['photoUrls'],
        tags = json['tags'],
        status = json['status'];

  Map toJson() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'name': name,
      'category': category,
      'photoUrls': photoUrls,
      'tags': tags,
      'status': status
    };
  }
}
```

My problem is my code gets the first image and shows it,
but I dont know how to implement it for **multiple images**, I guess I have to parse this XML list into a list first, but I don't know how to do this.
The output should be something like this:

```
List image_urls = [URL1, URL2, URL3]
```

here is my code so far:
could anyone help me with this?

```
child: 
            FutureBuilder<List<Pet>>(
                    future: API.get_pets(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                          return Column(
                            children: [
                              Text("Actual Pet: " + category.toString()),   
                              Expanded(
                                child: PageView.builder(
                                  itemCount: number_of_parameters,
                                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                    Pet pet = snapshot.data![index];
                                    category = pet.category.toString();
                                    return Card(
                                      child: Container(
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                borderRadius:
                                                    BorderRadius.circular(15),
                                                image: DecorationImage(
                                                    image: image(photoURL).image,
                                                    fit: BoxFit.fitWidth),
                                              ),
                                        child: Column(children: [
                                          Text ("": category)
                                        ]),),);},),),
                            ],
                          );
                      return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                      },},),);
```

**PS: After using xml package:**

```
 FutureBuilder<String>(
                    future: API.get_pets_full(randomly_select_URL()),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        if (dropDownIsSelected == true) {
                          var number_of_parameters = snapshot.data!.length;
                          var random_pet = random.nextInt(number_of_parameters);
                          return Expanded(
                            child: PageView.builder(
                              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                              itemCount: number_of_parameters,
                              onPageChanged: (int index) {
                                setState(() {
                                  dropdownvalue = null;
                                  dropDownIsSelected = false;
                                });
                              },
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                String pet_data = snapshot.data![random_pet]; //[id, name, category, status, imageUrls];
                                print('PET_DATA');
                                print(pet_data);
                                final doc = XmlDocument.parse(pet_data);
                                print("DOC");
                                print(doc);

                                var id = doc.findAllElements('id').first.text;
                                var name = doc.findAllElements('name').first.text;
                                var category = doc.findAllElements('category').first.text;
                                var status = doc.findAllElements('status').first.text;
                                final photoUrls = doc.findAllElements('photoUrl').map((e) => e.text).toList();
                                print(photoUrls);
```

And The get_pets full function is like this:

```
  static Future<String> get_pets_full(selectedURL) async {
    selectedURL ??=
        'MY_API';
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(selectedURL),headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/xml',
  },);
  print(response.body); 
   return response.body;  
  }
```

Comment: Give examples of output from the print statements - i.e. response.body, pet_data and doc

Comment: it gives an error of `XmlParserException (XmlParserException: "<" expected at 1:1)
` on the ` final doc = XmlDocument.parse(pet_data);` line, and `print(pet_data)` gives a one letter output like q or B ...

Comment: In which case, what makes you think you can parse `pet_data` as XML?? a single letter cannot possible be XML. What does response.body look like?

Comment: response.body is a XML like `<ArrayList><item><id>1</id><category><id>101</id><name>Bunny</name></category><name>Bundor Bunny</name><photoUrls><photoUrl>data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/4QAiRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgAAQESAAMAAAABAAEAAAAAAAD/4gxYSUNDX1BST0ZJTEUAAQEAAAxITGlubwIQAAB...`

Comment: I have some data about pets, and sometimes with multiple photoUrls for one pet, I think it would be easier to parse them into XML, to handle that multiple photos @RichardHeap

Comment: Updated the answer... It works in JSON or XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `xml` package. Parse the document, then find the elements, which will give you an iterator of elements. Extract the `text` and form a list.

```
final doc = XmlDocument.parse(input);
final imageUrls = doc.findAllElements('photoURL').map((e) => e.text).toList();
```

**EDIT**

It seems based on your other question that your API will supply either JSON or XML. Parsing the list of URLs out of either is pretty simple. Note that there's a typo in your question; you show the tag as `photoURL` but in fact it's `photoUrl`.

Here's complete code showing both versions. (You can try the JSON version in Dartpad.)

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:xml/xml.dart';

void main() async {
  var uri = Uri.parse(
    'https://yadda.yadda.io/api/v3/pet/findByStatus?status=available',
  );

  // The XML way
  final response = await http.get(
    uri,
    headers: {'Accept': 'application/xml'},
  );

  final doc = XmlDocument.parse(response.body);
  final imageUrls = doc.findAllElements('photoUrl').map((e) => e.text).toList();
  print(imageUrls);

  // The JSON way
  final r2 = await http.get(uri);
  final j = json.decode(r2.body);
  final images = (j[0]['photoUrls'] as List<dynamic>).cast<String>();
  print(images);
}
```

Comment: doesn't work for me, is there anything else that I need to consider?

Comment: What doesn't work? What bits do? What happens if you print `doc`? What happens if you do `doc.findAllElements('photoURL').forEach(print);` ?

Comment: printing doc gives me only `q`
and `doc.findAllElements('photoURL')` gives `XmlParserException (XmlParserException: "<" expected at 1:1)` Error

Comment: Update your question showing your XML processing code.

Comment: Thank you I am going to test it soon, really appreciate your time

Comment: Sorry I dont understand how to integrate this code with my pageView widget and where to add this, could you explain it please

Comment: That would surely be a different question. The title of this one is `parsing an XML list` which is done. Done let the scope of the question creep. Accept this; ask another showing specifically what you tried and what didn't work.